# git / git-extensions versions correspondance table - Which version of git is embedded in git-extensions 2.32?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I looked for a correspondence table between a version of git-extension and the version of embedded git, and I did not find it.

Does someone know such a resource, or the answer to the question in the title ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restored from repository

```
GitEx 2.42 - Git 1.8
GitEx 2.41 - Git 1.7.11
GitEx 2.32 - Git 1.7.10
GitEx 2.29 - Git 1.7.9
GitEx 2.27 - Git 1.7.8
GitEx 2.25 - Git 1.7.7
...
GitEx 1.55 - Git 1.6.2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but where did you find that ? What do you mean by "Restored from repository" ?

Comment: Check history for Bin folder in GitEx repository. Every commit has a tag, which version it appeared